# "Code generation for property failed" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was doing some clean-up to get rid of the unused resources in our project. After the cleanup, I had a succssfull build but now during every build I randomly get the error below.

The projects builds and runs fine but I guess a reference of the resources is still laying around somewhere in the codebase although search results return nothing for the file specified.

Any ideas how I can get rid of this error ?

[image]

Comment: How and for what did you search? Try using Notepad++ or another external editor as Visual Studio won't always search in all files, and search for just "tips1", case-insensitive. Did you save all and restart Visual Studio, just in case?

Comment: I will try the "magical" restart. Also how do I search the entire project with notepad++ ?

Comment: Search -> Search ... -> Tab 'Search In Files' and then there's an option to search recursive.

Comment: @CodeCaster Restart seemed to work for now